# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined in Javascript module

Tags: javascript, frontend

The following javascript module add a simple `div` into html file. When I called `board.drawIn()`, everything works well. But when I called `board.initIn()`, I got,

```sh
gomoku.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'board')
```

I'm quite confused because `initIn()` function actually does nothing but call `drawIn()` directally. Anyone can help?

```js
const board = (() => {
    function drawIn(container) {
        this.board = document.createElement('div');
        this.board.classList.add('gomokuBoard');
        container.appendChild(this.board);
    }

    function initIn(container) {
        drawIn(container);
    }

    return { drawIn, initIn };

})();

const gomoku = (() => {
    function initIn(container) {
        //board.drawIn(container);    /* this works */
        board.initIn(container);      /* doesn't work */
    }

    return { initIn };
})();

gomoku.initIn(document.querySelector('body'));
```

```css
.gomokuBoard {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: it's because `this` is undefined

Comment: `drawIn(container);` is a call expression statement without a base reference. Why do you expect `this` to be `board` inside `drawIn` when called like this? There’s no connection between the two.

Comment: I called `board.initIn(container)`, so `this` should be `board` object?

Comment: No, that's not correct, only works if you instantiate an instance using `new`

Comment: @shen `this` is `board` _inside `initIn` only_. You don’t use `this` there. Then you go on to call `drawIn(container);`; the `this` reference is not used here, so it’s lost. If you want to use `board.initIn(container)`, then the `drawIn` call should look like `drawIn.call(this);`, for example.

Comment: So I should call `this.drawIn(container);`? I tried, it works.

Comment: @shen See my edited comment. `this.drawIn` may work here, but it won’t work in similar situations.

Comment: Ok I understand now, thanks a lot Bravo and Sebastian Simon.  `this` in Javascript almost kill me since I was a Java programmer...